# Inserting records to database using JQuery Ajax call is not working

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

Friends, I'm new to this jQuery ajax call. 
I want to insert data to database without postback. 
currently it's working with postback, please find the bug and help. 
here i have used jQuery ajax call, in this I'm getting data and 
pass it to the webservice for inserting the records in background
without postback but it will get postback and inserting the records.

Here I have used simply three records for testing purposes.

**Default.aspx CODE**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnsubmit').click(function () {
                var firstname = $('#txtfirstname').val();
                var lastname = $('#txtlastname').val();
                var occupation = $('#txtoccupation').val();

                $.ajax({

                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'Default.aspx/savedata',
                    data: "{'firstname':'" + firstname + "','lastname':'" + lastname + "','occupation':'" + occupation + "'}",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#txtfirstname').val(''); $('#txtlastname').val(''); $('#txtoccupation').val('');
                        //alert("Record saved successfully in database");
                    },
                    error: function () {

                        alert("some problem in saving data");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>    
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs CODE**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public static string savedata(string firstname, string lastname, string occupation)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into profileinfo values('" + firstname + "','" + lastname + "','" + occupation + "')", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return "Success";

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return "failed";
        }
    }
    protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

Step 1:

Add Name space:

```
using System.Web.Services;

[WebMethod]
public static string savedata(string firstname, string lastname, string occupation)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());

    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into profileinfo values('" + firstname + "','" + lastname + "','" + occupation + "')", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        return "Success";
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        return "failed";
     }
}
```

in javascript please  Try This

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnsubmit').click(function () {
                var firstname = $('#txtfirstname').val();
                var lastname = $('#txtlastname').val();
                var occupation = $('#txtoccupation').val();

                $.ajax({

                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'Default.aspx/savedata',
                    data: "{'firstname':'" + firstname + "','lastname':'" + lastname + "','occupation':'" + occupation + "'}",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#txtfirstname').val(''); $('#txtlastname').val(''); $('#txtoccupation').val('');
                        //alert("Record saved successfully in database");
                    },
                    error: function () {

                        alert("some problem in saving data");
                    }
                });
           return false;  //Plese return false in your js
            });
        });
```

Comment: Hi to avoid post back use return false  in Button Click event.

Comment: just return false in javascript. i have updated the code please try

Answer (score 0):

If you are using input button with type="submit" or asp:Button with runat="server" change it to

```
<input type="button" id="btnsubmit" value="TextHere">
```

And also change you error function like this it will give you the exact error if any

```
error: function (err) {

                    alert(JSON.stringify(err)));
                }
```

And there is no need for this function if you are using ajax

```
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add name space using System.Web.Services;
then add [webmethod] befor your static string function.It will work.